# Json.NET is ridiculously slow when deployed to Windows Azure?

Tags: .net, json, serialization, azure, json.net

My `MVC4` project's using `Json.NET` Version 5.0.6 to de/serialize `DTO` objects for communicating with worker roles.

Everything is fine when debug locally, the de/serialization take about only 60-100ms. But after deployed to `Azure VM`(medium size), it takes about 2000ms to serialize the same `DTO` objects.

Here is the measurement code,

```
var start = DateTime.Now;
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Data);
response.Output.Write(json);
response.Output.Flush();
var end = DateTime.Now;
var timeTaken = (end - start).TotalMilliseconds;
```

Obviously it's something wrong, but I can't figure it out. Can someone give me some advice or had similar experience?

Thx a lot!

Comment: Are you sure you're only measuring the serialization/deserialization rather than any database activity? In other words, do you *definitely* have the objects in memory before trying to serialize, or are you using something like `IQueryable` which could defer the fetching?

Comment: Actually I have converted all entity objects into DTOs which has no any relations with DB. I've attached the code for measurement of the serialization/deserialization time taken.

Comment: don't use `DateTime.Now` for benchmarks

Comment: @Daniel A.White: Can you be more explicit please?

Comment: The resolution of the `DateTime.Now` is too imprecise. Use a `Stopwatch` instead.

Comment: You may benefit from reading Eric Lippert's articles on performance benchmarking mistakes.  [Part 1](http://tech.pro/blog/1293/c-performance-benchmark-mistakes-part-one) [Part 2](http://tech.pro/tutorial/1295/c-performance-benchmark-mistakes-part-two) [Part 3](http://tech.pro/tutorial/1317/c-performance-benchmark-mistakes-part-three)